# Create a colored hillshade in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hillshade

Is it possible (and how) to create a colored hillshade using a color other than gray in ArcGIS Desktop as it is possible in ArcGIS Pro as described in this article by John Nelson on the ArcGIS Blog?
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/kandy-kolored-multidirectional-streamlined-hillshade/

Comment: Multidimensional: yes through ArcMap or AGOL. https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/arcuser/multi-directional-hillshade-makes-your-maps-pop/?rmedium=arcuser&rsource=http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/fall-2014/multi-directional-hillshade-makes-your-maps-pop.

Comment: Note to posters: I and many others cannot view these video-heavy articles referenced. Video services like YouTube were blocked to reduced band use by my workplace during pandemic.